# Xpath or Xquery with Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is it possible to use Xpath or Xquery to query XML type fields in a database using Eloquent ORM ? I find in inconvenient to parse the XML every time and filter my results in memory. I would rather return my results from a query, is there a way to achieve that using Eloquent or I'm stuck with raw database statements?

Thank you

Comment: It's very specific feature. I think you need to implement own lib over eloquent to do it or use raw statement.

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed the options for selecting items in Eloquent and there is not much good options to select based on XML values as you expect. You can use some wildcards and run calculations on Eloquent to filter needed data but none of these are very efficient.